# How to make location-list focused?

Tags: vim

I'm using Syntastic Vim extension which shows errors in location-list window.

When I open location list with `:lopen` I can choose any location by moving up and down with <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to the error in current buffer. Then when I want to make this location-list window active again to move to another error I need type `:lopen` command again.

I think there must be some shortcut or another quick way to switch between buffer and location-list window. Does anybody know any?

Comment: Did you know [Syntastic comes with an exhaustive documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L437)?

Comment: @romainl I do. I've read the tutorial (`:help Syntastic` which you mentioned) and README.md (on Github) end to end. I just thought that ask question now would be far more easier than delve deeper on my own.

Comment: That's quite possible the worst way to address your issue. The answer to your question is in the documentation. Read it and you will solve your problem.

Comment: @romainl If you so sure, than why not cite the part of documentation, which contains the answer? Such obvious advice is of no help.

Comment: I think my question is about using location-list. I've read part of location-list Vim documentation either, but haven't noticed use case my question is about.

Comment: 1. The quickfix window doesn't close itself automatically; it's that plugin that's doing that. 2. My link points to the exact solution to your problem: a *syntastic* option. 3. You would have found that solution if you had had the patience to RTFM.